# Change the sequence of div an span in this Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I need help.
Is there anybody can change the sequence of the div "cookieinfo-close" and the following "span" element. I want first the span, second the div.
Thank you!

```
!function(e){"use strict";var t=e,i=t.document,o="cbinstance";var n={get:function(e){return decodeURIComponent(i.cookie.replace(new RegExp("(?:(?:^|.*;)\\s*"+encodeURIComponent(e).replace(/[\-\.\+\*]/g,"\\$&")+"\\s*\\=\\s*([^;]*).*$)|^.*$"),"$1"))||null},set:function(e,t,o,n,s,r){if(!e||/^(?:expires|max\-age|path|domain|secure)$/i.test(e))return!1;var a="";if(o)switch(o.constructor){case Number:a=o===1/0?"; expires=Fri, 31 Dec 9999 23:59:59 GMT":"; max-age="+o;break;case String:a="; expires="+o;break;case Date:a="; expires="+o.toUTCString()}return i.cookie=encodeURIComponent(e)+"="+encodeURIComponent(t)+a+(s?"; domain="+s:"")+(n?"; path="+n:"")+(r?"; secure":""),!0},has:function(e){return new RegExp("(?:^|;\\s*)"+encodeURIComponent(e).replace(/[\-\.\+\*]/g,"\\$&")+"\\s*\\=").test(i.cookie)},remove:function(e,t,o){return!(!e||!this.has(e))&&(i.cookie=encodeURIComponent(e)+"=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT"+(o?"; domain="+o:"")+(t?"; path="+t:""),!0)}},s={merge:function(){var e,t={},i=0,o=arguments.length;if(0===o)return t;for(;i<o;i++)for(e in arguments[i])Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(arguments[i],e)&&(t[e]=arguments[i][e]);return t},str2bool:function(e){switch((e=""+e).toLowerCase()){case"false":case"no":case"0":case"":return!1;default:return!0}},fade_in:function(e){e.style.opacity<1&&(e.style.opacity=(parseFloat(e.style.opacity)+.05).toFixed(2),t.setTimeout(function(){s.fade_in(e)},50))},get_data_attribs:function(e){var t={};if(Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(e,"dataset"))t=e.dataset;else{var i,o=e.attributes;for(i in o)if(Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(o,i)){var n=o[i];if(/^data-/.test(n.name))t[s.camelize(n.name.substr(5))]=n.value}}return t},normalize_keys:function(e){var t={};for(var i in e)if(Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(e,i)){var o=s.camelize(i);t[o]=e[o]?e[o]:e[i]}return t},camelize:function(e){for(var t="-",i=e.indexOf(t);-1!=i;){var o=i===e.length-1,n=o?"":e[i+1],s=n.toUpperCase(),r=o?t:t+n;i=(e=e.replace(r,s)).indexOf(t)}return e},find_script_by_id:function(e){for(var t=i.getElementsByTagName("script"),o=0,n=t.length;o<n;o++)if(e===t[o].id)return t[o];return null}},r=s.find_script_by_id("cookieinfo"),a=e.cookieinfo=function(e){this.init(e)};a.prototype={cookiejar:n,init:function(t){this.inserted=!1,this.closed=!1,this.test_mode=!1;if(this.default_options={cookie:"we-love-cookies",closeText:"&#10006;",cookiePath:"/",debug:!1,expires:1/0,zindex:1e20,mask:!1,maskOpacity:.5,maskBackground:"#999",height:"auto",minHeight:"31px",bg:"#eee",fg:"#333",link:"#31A8F0",divlink:"#000",divlinkbg:"#F1D600",position:"top",message:"This is a cookie message.",linkmsg:"Read more.",scriptmsg:"Cookie Info Script",moreinfo:"#acc-430",tracking:"data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAAAACH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==",effect:null,fontSize:"14px",fontFamily:"verdana, arial, sans-serif",instance:o,textAlign:"center",acceptOnScroll:!1},this.options=this.default_options,this.script_el=r,this.script_el){var i=s.get_data_attribs(this.script_el);this.options=s.merge(this.options,i)}t&&(t=s.normalize_keys(t),this.options=s.merge(this.options,t)),o=this.options.instance,this.options.zindex=parseInt(this.options.zindex,10),this.options.mask=s.str2bool(this.options.mask),"string"==typeof this.options.expires&&"function"==typeof e[this.options.expires]&&(this.options.expires=e[this.options.expires]),"function"==typeof this.options.expires&&(this.options.expires=this.options.expires()),this.script_el&&this.run()},log:function(){"undefined"!=typeof console&&console.log.apply(console,arguments)},run:function(){if(!this.agreed()){var e=this;!function(e,t){var i=!1,o=!0,n=e.document,s=n.documentElement,r=n.addEventListener?"addEventListener":"attachEvent",a=n.addEventListener?"removeEventListener":"detachEvent",c=n.addEventListener?"":"on",l=function(o){"readystatechange"==o.type&&"complete"!=n.readyState||(("load"==o.type?e:n)[a](c+o.type,l,!1),!i&&(i=!0)&&t.call(e,o.type||o))},p=function(){try{s.doScroll("left")}catch(e){return void setTimeout(p,50)}l("poll")};if("complete"==n.readyState)t.call(e,"lazy");else{if(n.createEventObject&&s.doScroll){try{o=!e.frameElement}catch(e){}o&&p()}n[r](c+"DOMContentLoaded",l,!1),n[r](c+"readystatechange",l,!1),e[r](c+"load",l,!1)}}(t,function(){e.insert()})}},build_viewport_mask:function(){var e=null;if(!0===this.options.mask){var t=this.options.maskOpacity,o='<div id="cookieinfo-mask" style="position:fixed;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;background:'+this.options.maskBackground+";zoom:1;filter:alpha(opacity="+100*t+");opacity:"+t+";z-index:"+this.options.zindex+';"></div>',n=i.createElement("div");n.innerHTML=o,e=n.firstChild}return e},agree:function(){return this.cookiejar.set(this.options.cookie,1,this.options.expires,this.options.cookiePath),!0},agreed:function(){return this.cookiejar.has(this.options.cookie)},close:function(){return this.inserted&&(this.closed||(this.element&&this.element.parentNode.removeChild(this.element),this.element_mask&&this.element_mask.parentNode.removeChild(this.element_mask),this.closed=!0)),this.closed},agree_and_close:function(){return this.agree(),this.close()},cleanup:function(){return this.close(),this.unload()},unload:function(){return this.script_el&&this.script_el.parentNode.removeChild(this.script_el),e[o]=void 0,!0},insert:function(){this.element_mask=this.build_viewport_mask();var e=this.options.zindex;this.element_mask&&(e+=1);var t=i.createElement("div");t.className="cookieinfo",t.style.position="fixed",t.style.left=0,t.style.right=0,t.style.height=this.options.height,t.style.minHeight=this.options.minHeight,t.style.zIndex=e,t.style.background=this.options.bg,t.style.color=this.options.fg,t.style.lineHeight=t.style.minHeight,t.style.padding="8px 30px",t.style.fontFamily=this.options.fontFamily,t.style.fontSize=this.options.fontSize,t.style.textAlign=this.options.textAlign,"top"===this.options.position?t.style.top=0:t.style.bottom=0,t.innerHTML='<div class="cookieinfo-close" style="float:right;display:block;padding:5px 8px 5px 8px;min-width:100px;margin-left:5px;border-top-left-radius:5px;border-top-right-radius:5px;border-bottom-right-radius:5px;border-bottom-left-radius:5px;border-bottom-left-radius:5px;">'+this.options.closeText+'</div><span style="display:block;padding:5px 0 5px 0;">'+this.options.message+" <a>"+this.options.linkmsg+"</a><img> <a>"+this.options.scriptmsg+"</a></span>",this.element=t;var o=t.getElementsByTagName("a")[0];o.href=this.options.moreinfo,o.style.textDecoration="underline",o.style.color=this.options.link;var n=t.getElementsByTagName("a")[1];n.href=this.options.scriptinfo,n.style.textDecoration="none",n.style.display="none",n.style.color=this.options.link;var r=t.getElementsByTagName("div")[0];r.style.cursor="pointer",r.style.color=this.options.divlink,r.style.background=this.options.divlinkbg,r.style.textAlign="center";var a=t.getElementsByTagName("img")[0];function c(e,t,i){var o=e.addEventListener?"addEventListener":"attachEvent",n=e.addEventListener?"":"on";e[o](n+t,i,!1)}a.src=this.options.tracking,a.style.display="none";var l=this;c(r,"click",function(){l.agree_and_close()}),this.element_mask&&(c(this.element_mask,"click",function(){l.agree_and_close()}),i.body.appendChild(this.element_mask)),this.options.acceptOnScroll&&c(window,"scroll",function(){l.agree_and_close()}),i.body.appendChild(this.element),this.inserted=!0,"fade"===this.options.effect?(this.element.style.opacity=0,s.fade_in(this.element)):this.element.style.opacity=1}},r&&(e[o]||(e[o]=new a))}(window);
```

Comment: Nope. Not working with obfuscated code. Not happening.

Comment: Please, if you want any help with this, format it properly.

Comment: Hello. Welcome to StackOverflow. The code snippet you have shared appears to be a minified js file and is hard to read/reason about. Please consider reading the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide and creating a [Minimum Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to help people trying to diagnose this with a little bit of context. Cheers :)

Comment: I'm sorry to say this but with these type of questions you are not going to get anything except downvotes.

Comment: Hello there, I'm really sorry. First time here. 
Yes this is a minified JS. I have no idea how to format it properly. Is there a page where I can do that, or a program like Dreamweaver? I know that I can fix there CSS e.g. ...

Comment: use http://jsbeautifier.org/ , but it looks like the code is uglified so it will be difficult to read the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to revert your [js file to unminify](http://unminify.com/):

```
! function(e) {
    "use strict";
    var t = e,
        i = t.document,
        o = "cbinstance";
    var n = {
            get: function(e) {
                return decodeURIComponent(i.cookie.replace(new RegExp("(?:(?:^|.*;)\\s*" + encodeURIComponent(e).replace(/[\-\.\+\*]/g, "\\$&") + "\\s*\\=\\s*([^;]*).*$)|^.*$"), "$1")) || null
            },
            set: function(e, t, o, n, s, r) {
                if (!e || /^(?:expires|max\-age|path|domain|secure)$/i.test(e)) return !1;
                var a = "";
                if (o) switch (o.constructor) {
                    case Number:
                        a = o === 1 / 0 ? "; expires=Fri, 31 Dec 9999 23:59:59 GMT" : "; max-age=" + o;
                        break;
                    case String:
                        a = "; expires=" + o;
                        break;
                    case Date:
                        a = "; expires=" + o.toUTCString()
                }
                return i.cookie = encodeURIComponent(e) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(t) + a + (s ? "; domain=" + s : "") + (n ? "; path=" + n : "") + (r ? "; secure" : ""), !0
            },
            has: function(e) {
                return new RegExp("(?:^|;\\s*)" + encodeURIComponent(e).replace(/[\-\.\+\*]/g, "\\$&") + "\\s*\\=").test(i.cookie)
            },
            remove: function(e, t, o) {
                return !(!e || !this.has(e)) && (i.cookie = encodeURIComponent(e) + "=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT" + (o ? "; domain=" + o : "") + (t ? "; path=" + t : ""), !0)
            }
        },
        s = {
            merge: function() {
                var e, t = {},
                    i = 0,
                    o = arguments.length;
                if (0 === o) return t;
                for (; i < o; i++)
                    for (e in arguments[i]) Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(arguments[i], e) && (t[e] = arguments[i][e]);
                return t
            },
            str2bool: function(e) {
                switch ((e = "" + e).toLowerCase()) {
                    case "false":
                    case "no":
                    case "0":
                    case "":
                        return !1;
                    default:
                        return !0
                }
            },
            fade_in: function(e) {
                e.style.opacity < 1 && (e.style.opacity = (parseFloat(e.style.opacity) + .05).toFixed(2), t.setTimeout(function() {
                    s.fade_in(e)
                }, 50))
            },
            get_data_attribs: function(e) {
                var t = {};
                if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(e, "dataset")) t = e.dataset;
                else {
                    var i, o = e.attributes;
                    for (i in o)
                        if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(o, i)) {
                            var n = o[i];
                            if (/^data-/.test(n.name)) t[s.camelize(n.name.substr(5))] = n.value
                        }
                }
                return t
            },
            normalize_keys: function(e) {
                var t = {};
                for (var i in e)
                    if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(e, i)) {
                        var o = s.camelize(i);
                        t[o] = e[o] ? e[o] : e[i]
                    }
                return t
            },
            camelize: function(e) {
                for (var t = "-", i = e.indexOf(t); - 1 != i;) {
                    var o = i === e.length - 1,
                        n = o ? "" : e[i + 1],
                        s = n.toUpperCase(),
                        r = o ? t : t + n;
                    i = (e = e.replace(r, s)).indexOf(t)
                }
                return e
            },
            find_script_by_id: function(e) {
                for (var t = i.getElementsByTagName("script"), o = 0, n = t.length; o < n; o++)
                    if (e === t[o].id) return t[o];
                return null
            }
        },
        r = s.find_script_by_id("cookieinfo"),
        a = e.cookieinfo = function(e) {
            this.init(e)
        };
    a.prototype = {
        cookiejar: n,
        init: function(t) {
            this.inserted = !1, this.closed = !1, this.test_mode = !1;
            if (this.default_options = {
                    cookie: "we-love-cookies",
                    closeText: "&#10006;",
                    cookiePath: "/",
                    debug: !1,
                    expires: 1 / 0,
                    zindex: 1e20,
                    mask: !1,
                    maskOpacity: .5,
                    maskBackground: "#999",
                    height: "auto",
                    minHeight: "31px",
                    bg: "#eee",
                    fg: "#333",
                    link: "#31A8F0",
                    divlink: "#000",
                    divlinkbg: "#F1D600",
                    position: "top",
                    message: "This is a cookie message.",
                    linkmsg: "Read more.",
                    scriptmsg: "Cookie Info Script",
                    moreinfo: "#acc-430",
                    tracking: "data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAAAACH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==",
                    effect: null,
                    fontSize: "14px",
                    fontFamily: "verdana, arial, sans-serif",
                    instance: o,
                    textAlign: "center",
                    acceptOnScroll: !1
                }, this.options = this.default_options, this.script_el = r, this.script_el) {
                var i = s.get_data_attribs(this.script_el);
                this.options = s.merge(this.options, i)
            }
            t && (t = s.normalize_keys(t), this.options = s.merge(this.options, t)), o = this.options.instance, this.options.zindex = parseInt(this.options.zindex, 10), this.options.mask = s.str2bool(this.options.mask), "string" == typeof this.options.expires && "function" == typeof e[this.options.expires] && (this.options.expires = e[this.options.expires]), "function" == typeof this.options.expires && (this.options.expires = this.options.expires()), this.script_el && this.run()
        },
        log: function() {
            "undefined" != typeof console && console.log.apply(console, arguments)
        },
        run: function() {
            if (!this.agreed()) {
                var e = this;
                ! function(e, t) {
                    var i = !1,
                        o = !0,
                        n = e.document,
                        s = n.documentElement,
                        r = n.addEventListener ? "addEventListener" : "attachEvent",
                        a = n.addEventListener ? "removeEventListener" : "detachEvent",
                        c = n.addEventListener ? "" : "on",
                        l = function(o) {
                            "readystatechange" == o.type && "complete" != n.readyState || (("load" == o.type ? e : n)[a](c + o.type, l, !1), !i && (i = !0) && t.call(e, o.type || o))
                        },
                        p = function() {
                            try {
                                s.doScroll("left")
                            } catch (e) {
                                return void setTimeout(p, 50)
                            }
                            l("poll")
                        };
                    if ("complete" == n.readyState) t.call(e, "lazy");
                    else {
                        if (n.createEventObject && s.doScroll) {
                            try {
                                o = !e.frameElement
                            } catch (e) {}
                            o && p()
                        }
                        n[r](c + "DOMContentLoaded", l, !1), n[r](c + "readystatechange", l, !1), e[r](c + "load", l, !1)
                    }
                }(t, function() {
                    e.insert()
                })
            }
        },
        build_viewport_mask: function() {
            var e = null;
            if (!0 === this.options.mask) {
                var t = this.options.maskOpacity,
                    o = '<div id="cookieinfo-mask" style="position:fixed;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;background:' + this.options.maskBackground + ";zoom:1;filter:alpha(opacity=" + 100 * t + ");opacity:" + t + ";z-index:" + this.options.zindex + ';"></div>',
                    n = i.createElement("div");
                n.innerHTML = o, e = n.firstChild
            }
            return e
        },
        agree: function() {
            return this.cookiejar.set(this.options.cookie, 1, this.options.expires, this.options.cookiePath), !0
        },
        agreed: function() {
            return this.cookiejar.has(this.options.cookie)
        },
        close: function() {
            return this.inserted && (this.closed || (this.element && this.element.parentNode.removeChild(this.element), this.element_mask && this.element_mask.parentNode.removeChild(this.element_mask), this.closed = !0)), this.closed
        },
        agree_and_close: function() {
            return this.agree(), this.close()
        },
        cleanup: function() {
            return this.close(), this.unload()
        },
        unload: function() {
            return this.script_el && this.script_el.parentNode.removeChild(this.script_el), e[o] = void 0, !0
        },
        insert: function() {
            this.element_mask = this.build_viewport_mask();
            var e = this.options.zindex;
            this.element_mask && (e += 1);
            var t = i.createElement("div");
            t.className = "cookieinfo", t.style.position = "fixed", t.style.left = 0, t.style.right = 0, t.style.height = this.options.height, t.style.minHeight = this.options.minHeight, t.style.zIndex = e, t.style.background = this.options.bg, t.style.color = this.options.fg, t.style.lineHeight = t.style.minHeight, t.style.padding = "8px 30px", t.style.fontFamily = this.options.fontFamily, t.style.fontSize = this.options.fontSize, t.style.textAlign = this.options.textAlign, "top" === this.options.position ? t.style.top = 0 : t.style.bottom = 0, t.innerHTML = '<div class="cookieinfo-close" style="float:right;display:block;padding:5px 8px 5px 8px;min-width:100px;margin-left:5px;border-top-left-radius:5px;border-top-right-radius:5px;border-bottom-right-radius:5px;border-bottom-left-radius:5px;border-bottom-left-radius:5px;">' + this.options.closeText + '</div><span style="display:block;padding:5px 0 5px 0;">' + this.options.message + " <a>" + this.options.linkmsg + "</a><img> <a>" + this.options.scriptmsg + "</a></span>", this.element = t;
            var o = t.getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
            o.href = this.options.moreinfo, o.style.textDecoration = "underline", o.style.color = this.options.link;
            var n = t.getElementsByTagName("a")[1];
            n.href = this.options.scriptinfo, n.style.textDecoration = "none", n.style.display = "none", n.style.color = this.options.link;
            var r = t.getElementsByTagName("div")[0];
            r.style.cursor = "pointer", r.style.color = this.options.divlink, r.style.background = this.options.divlinkbg, r.style.textAlign = "center";
            var a = t.getElementsByTagName("img")[0];

            function c(e, t, i) {
                var o = e.addEventListener ? "addEventListener" : "attachEvent",
                    n = e.addEventListener ? "" : "on";
                e[o](n + t, i, !1)
            }
            a.src = this.options.tracking, a.style.display = "none";
            var l = this;
            c(r, "click", function() {
                l.agree_and_close()
            }), this.element_mask && (c(this.element_mask, "click", function() {
                l.agree_and_close()
            }), i.body.appendChild(this.element_mask)), this.options.acceptOnScroll && c(window, "scroll", function() {
                l.agree_and_close()
            }), i.body.appendChild(this.element), this.inserted = !0, "fade" === this.options.effect ? (this.element.style.opacity = 0, s.fade_in(this.element)) : this.element.style.opacity = 1
        }
    }, r && (e[o] || (e[o] = new a))
}(window);
```

then you should precise your question, as I understand you want the innerHTML content `<span></span>` be the first place then this element `<div class="cookieinfo-close"></div>` to be the second place?
If so replace t.innerHTML cod as follow:

```
t.innerHTML = '<span style="display:block;padding:5px 0 5px 0;">' + 
               this.options.message + " <a>" + this.options.linkmsg + "</a><img> <a>" + this.options.scriptmsg + '</a></span><div class="cookieinfo-close">', 
               + this.options.closeText + '</div>',
               this.element = t;
```

in order to make js file more readable I had remove inline style code and you should add follow to your css file:

```
.cookieinfo-close {
  float:right;
  display:block;
  padding:5px 8px 5px 8px;
  min-width:100px;
  margin-left:5px;
  border-top-left-radius:5px;
  border-top-right-radius:5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius:5px;
  border-bottom-left-radius:5px;
  border-bottom-left-radius:5px;
}
```

Once done test to see if this you want to modify, and one more thing change the library js file usually not recommend, try to modify layout css first, removed the inline style first in this js file then you could easily to override by your own css file